# Rasa RegexFeaturizer is it based on token or whole sentence?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

```
- regex: regex features for intent classification
  examples: |
    - \bon road pric/i
    - \bonroad pric/i
```

I have tested above regex and they are working fine. Hence I am sure there is no issue with regex expression

Example:

```
training-row-1] Please tell me on road price now.  
training-row-2] Please tell me price now.
```

Based on above regex pattern, regex features which should get added are:

```
training-row-1] Please tell me on road price now. ==> TRUE (because regex match)
training-row-2] Please tell me price now.         ==> FALSE (regex don't match)
```

**My question is, In RegexFeaturizer, does regex match happens on whole sentence or on each token?
It make sense to have it on whole sentence.**

Is above featurization which I have assumed is correct or no?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following docstring in the code for the `RegexFeaturizer`.

```py
"""
Given a sentence, returns a vector of {1,0} values indicating which
regexes did match. Furthermore, if the message is tokenized, the 
function will mark all tokens with a dict relating the name of the 
regex to whether it was matched.
"""
```

So I *think* it's taking the entire sentence as input. It's hard to see inside of the feature space in Rasa but I've confirmed that the correct entity is picked up across tokens when using the [RegexEntityExtractor](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components/#regexentityextractor). This is easily verified by temporarily adding entity examples in your NLU data (make sure it appears at least twice in intents) and running `rasa interactive`.

Comment: I am confused exactly because of this sentence. as it says if message is marked as tokens then for each token regex will be matched.

Comment: I am using RegexFeaturizer for intent classification and not for entity extraction. I have disabled it.